# Bootsrat html Toast does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toast

I have the html code below, if I put in normal HTML code, the Toast appears.

```
<div class="toast show" data-title="" 
  data-message="" 
  data-type="" 
  data-position-class="toast-bottom-right">
</div>
```

But if I do `<div id="msg"></div>`

and in jquery I do `$("#msg").html('<div class="toast-action" data-title="Hi, there!" data-message="Hope you like paper panel." data-type="success" data-position-class="toast-bottom-right"></div>')`

It does not work.

PS :  I do see the code attached to 
  if I inspect the page

Comment: Can you put your code in snippet?

Comment: In your HTML code, you provide a class called toast to the div. But in jQuery you didn't. Maybe try `class="toast toast-action"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#element').toast('show')`

and in your first div you can use `<div class="toast" data-delay="10000">` this is not a complete example, just showing that you need to set a delay option for how long the toast will be visible after your `.toast('show')` call.

See bootstraps official documentation for usage with jQuery.